# How to insert a string value in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using VB6 and SQL Server

How to insert a string value in the table

```
Dim a as string
a = 0008", "0009", "1011", "1208
```

I want to insert this string values in the table

Expected Output

Table1

```
ID

0008
0009
1011
1208
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Need Query Help.

Comment: I didn't know you could omit leading and trailing `"` in VB6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below way:

```
Dim a as string
a = "0008,0009,1011,1208"
dim strArray as string() = Split(a, ",")
```

b
    for each item as string in strArray

```
   query = "INSERT INTO  Table1(ID) values('"&item&"')"
   // Write Connection and Command code here
next
```

**Update:**

You can generate insert SQL statement for each item at a time and then write Connection and Command code, that would be more efficient.

```
dim query as string
for each item as string in strArray
   query = query + "INSERT INTO  Table1(ID) values('"&item&"'); "
next
// Write Connection and Command code here after generating insert statement 
// so that all data will save into database in one shot.
```

Comment: I am using VB6, You code is not working, showing error in "Split", Can you check plz....

Comment: I've changed my code block accordingly, would you please check on more time, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello @Gopal, I've updated my answer so that it can do in more efficient way, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(100)
SET @Str = '0008", "0009", "1011", "1208'
SET @Str = REPLACE(@Str,'"','')
SELECT * FROM [dbo].Split(@Str)
```

You can use Split function from this link.
Check this Split function.
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/split-string-in-sql-server-2005-clr-vs-t

Comment: We can pass complete string as parameter to SP.

Answer (score 0):

at first u must split this string to a string[]

```
dim a as string 

a = 0008", "0009", "1011", "1208
dim str as string() = (a.Replace('"',' ')).Split(",")
```

and if

```
a = "0008,0009,1011,1208"
dim str as string() = a.Split(",")
```

now add values in the table with a query on the foreach loop

imaging your table name is **testTable** andyour column name is  **ID**

```
 dim query as string
 for each item as string in str

            query = "INSERT INTO  testTable(ID) values('"&item&"')"
 next
```

Comment: `string[] str = a.Split(",");` is supposed to be `dim str as string() = a.Split(",");`

Comment: yap(;-) but without ';') at first i create sample in the c# and then i forget Correct this sample thanks

Comment: And when you're inserting, you should use **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL commands! Doing so open the door to SQL injection attacks - not something you want to have to deal with......